# I have TypeError for py3

Tags: python, python-requests

```
host="127.0.0.1"
port=int(8080)
with socket.socket() as socket:
    socket.bind(host, port)
    socket.listen()
```

Traceback:

```
socket.bind(host, port)
TypeError: bind() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

My error, i dont understand I just started learning python, but I keep getting errors, I wonder if I start writing linux.

Comment: I recommend actually learning python first before learning how to use sockets.

Comment: Yes thanks, I started with a really poor quality course. Even my friends told me to quit that course, but I clicked on socket one last time and there was no mistake I didn't get ... I will continue with a better quality course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.bind` takes a tuple as argument, try:

```
socket.bind((host, port))
```

---

Note:

`port=int(8080)` is redundant, use only `port=8080`

Answer (score 1):

The `socket.bind()` method only accepts one parameter, an address. You're trying to give it two parameters: host and port. You need to create a single address that combines your host and port values, then pass that address to `socket.bind()`.

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) has a bit more information on this, including the following sample code:

```
# create an INET, STREAMing socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# bind the socket to a public host, and a well-known port
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80))
# become a server socket
serversocket.listen(5)
```

Take note of the double parentheses in the `serversocket.bind()` call above: that extra set of parentheses is combining the hostname and port into a single parameter.